# Installing/Using Phantom JS 2.0.1 with Casper JS on Linux

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to install and use the Phantom JS Preview version 2.0.1 with Casper JS but I can't figure out how to make them work together.

I already have Phantom JS 1.9.8 installed and I have seen that 2.0.1 can be downloaded from here https://github.com/Vitallium/phantomjs/releases/tag/2.0.1 but then I really don't know how to use it (on its own or with Casper JS).

I have also tried to install it using `npm install -g phantomjs2@2.0.1` but I receive the following error

> Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs not in
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs2

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To install phantomjs2 on Linux :**

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pyppe/phantomjs2.0-ubuntu14.04x64/master/bin/phantomjs

sudo chmod 755 phantomjs

sudo cp ./phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

If you have an error, try to install libicu52 (can be found [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/201330288/libicu52_52.1-8_amd64.deb)).

Just to clarify, /usr/local/bin contains the binaries used during your session. Every time you download binaries, just put it there and you'll be able to launch them.

Comment: Hey @Maxime thanks for your answer but I would like to install Preview version 2.0.1 of PhantomJS not version 2.0

Any hint on this?

Comment: I cannot find 2.0.1 anywhere. Github, bitbucket ... Where did you see it ?

Comment: It's a fork so not sure it's gonna be merged into the real project. If you don't mind, you can use it ! Are you running windows ? Linux ? a Mac ?

Comment: At the bottom of your link, you can download the binary of phantomjs, it's really easy from there :) ! Just select the one you need (windows, linux, mac), download the zip file. Unzip. Open the folder, go to bin and launch phantomjs :)

Comment: If you wanna run it on linux, just do what i've done in my answer ;)  
Download, unzip, go tin bin, `sudo chmod 755 phantomjs; sudo cp ./phantomjs /usr/local/bin`. Then from anywhere : `phantomjs -v` should ouptut the version number 2.0.1 !

Comment: Yes man that did the trick! Could you explain me why copying `./phantomjs` to `/usr/loca/bin` did make it work? I think you should update your answer with this latest comment!